# How can we define "Pressure" as a tensor?

Tags: pressure, definition, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics, fluid-statics

We usually see in elementary textbooks that the quantity "Pressure" is taken as an scalar. But I heard it's actually a tensor and didn't hear anything more.

How can we define $P=\frac{F}{A}$ as a tensor?

Answer (score 1):

It can be derived from the virial theorem. The result is:

$$ P_{ij} = V^{-1}\left(\sum_k m_kv_k^iv_k^j + \sum_k r_k^if_k^j\right) $$

where $V$ is volume, $k$ is summed over all atoms in the system, $m_k$ is the mass of atom $k$, $v_k^i$ the $i$-th component of the velocity of atom $k$, $f_k^i$ the $i$-th component of the force on atom $k$. The second term is the virial.

Answer (score 0):

If you are familiar with dyadic notation, you can represent pressure as a tensor as follows:$$\vec{P}=p(\vec{i}_x\otimes \vec{i}_x+\vec{i}_y \otimes\vec{i}_y+\vec{i}_z\otimes\vec{i}_z)$$where the i's are the Cartesian unit vectors and p is the scalar we usually refer to as pressure.  If we take the dot product with a unit normal $\vec{n}=n_x\vec{i}_x+n_y\vec{i}_y+n_z\vec{i}_z$ to a surface of arbitrary orientation in the fluid, we obtain the force per unit area on the surface:$$\vec{P} \centerdot \vec{n}=p(\vec{i}_x\otimes \vec{i}_x+\vec{i}_y \otimes\vec{i}_y+\vec{i}_z\otimes\vec{i}_z)\centerdot(n_x\vec{i}_x+n_y\vec{i}_y+n_z\vec{i}_z)=p(n_x\vec{i}_x+n_y\vec{i}_y+n_z\vec{i}_z)$$or equivalently$$\vec{P} \centerdot \vec{n}=p\vec{n}$$
This force, as required, is oriented perpendicular to the surface.  Obtaining the force per unit area by dotting with a unit normal in this way is referred to as application of the *Cauchy Stress Relationship*.

The above development typically applies to static equilibrium situations.  In more general situations, where the fluid is deforming, the pressure is considered part of the overall stress tensor.  In such cases, the stress tensor $\vec{\sigma}$ is represented by:$$\vec{\sigma}=-p\vec{I}+\vec{\sigma_v}$$where the identity tensor $\vec{I}$ is given by$$\vec{I}=\vec{i}_x\otimes \vec{i}_x+\vec{i}_y \otimes\vec{i}_y+\vec{i}_z\otimes\vec{i}_z$$and where $\vec{\sigma_v}$ is the viscous contribution to the stress tensor.